# Strange Behavior of Calender.getTime()

Tags: java

My calender date is set to US/Pacific Timezone but when I print

```
    Calender dateCalender = getDateFromFile();
    System.out.println("Calender TimeZone: " + dateCalender.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Calender : " + dateCalender.getTime());
```

it prints the exactly same date/time but timezone IST (I am from India). For Example it prints

```
Calender TimeZone: **Pacific Standard Time**
Calender : Wed Oct 09 00:00:00 **IST** 2013
```

I tried to use debugger and tried to see dateCalender value it shows

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1381257000000,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Pacific",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Pacific,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=41,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=282,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

I don't understand this behavior of Calender `getTime`. Please let me know how I can print Date in Same Timezone format.

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using

Comment: It may be related to your OS's time settings.

Comment: Please show the code, how do you create the `dateCalender` instance?

Comment: Code provided please check now

Comment: Third attempt: what does your `getDateFromFile()` do? how does it create the `Calendar` instance?  (btw, it's `Calend*a*r, not Calend*e*r`)

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to output the date you receive from `Calendar#getTime()` in a format that includes the time zone you desire. The default output is to use your local time zone.

Comment: I want to print the date in its timezone which is already set. I dont want to use my own local timezone. Thats my question. Like in this example I want output Calender : Wed Oct 09 00:00:00 PST 2013

Comment: But you're using `getTime()` which is just a `Date` instance representing milliseconds from the epoch. That `Date` doesn't have the time zone information from your `Calendar` instance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no error in the code. `dateCalender.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()` prints out the time Zone associated to the calendar, while `dateCalender.getTime()` creates a date-object. Date-objects are always printed using the standard system time zone.

To print with the calendar timezone:

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    formatter.setTimeZone(dateCalender.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println(formatter.format(dateCalender.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thats my question how can I print date in its timezone. The timezone which is set for date.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set correct timezone while creating Calendar instance .

For example:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(
      GMT_TIMEZONE, EN_US_LOCALE);
```

In above code snippet we have set time zone as GMT so time will be shown in GMT same way you have to set US/Pacific TimeZone.

Check more about TimeZone class